# rspec and gem bullet test env fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rubygems

i want to run `rspec` with  `gem bullet` finding all the weak spots. 
i'm doing as follows:

Gemfile

```
group :development, :test do
  gem "bullet"
end
```

config/environments/test.rb

```
  config.after_initialize do
    Bullet.enable = true
    Bullet.rails_logger = true
    Bullet.raise = true # raise an error if n+1 query occurs
  end
```

spec/spec_helper.rb

```
    if Bullet.enable?
    config.before(:each) do
      Bullet.start_request
    end

    config.after(:each) do
      Bullet.perform_out_of_channel_notifications if Bullet.notification?
      Bullet.end_request
    end
  end
```

but when i try to run `rspec` i get error

```
% bundle exec rspec
/spec/spec_helper.rb:24:in `block in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant Bullet (NameError)
```

Please help me solve this problem

Comment: have you tried explicitly add `require 'bullet'` in spec helper?

Comment: Or, have you tried running `bundle exec rspec`?

Comment: addind `require` doesn't help. about `bundle exec` - i didn't include it in my question as i thought that's presumable. thanks for noting this

Comment: Can you try 'bundle list' to see if the gem is actually installed as part of your bundle ?

Comment: `% bundle list | grep bullet  
  * bullet (5.0.0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the follow strings into spec/rails_helper.rb file

```
RSpec.configure do |config|

  ...

  if Bullet.enable?
    config.before(:each) do
      Bullet.start_request
    end

    config.after(:each) do
      Bullet.perform_out_of_channel_notifications if Bullet.notification?
      Bullet.end_request
    end
  end

  ...

end
```

Answer (score 5):

At my side, I need to add

```
require "active_record"
require "bullet"
```

both in `spec/spec_helper.rb` and `environments/test.rb`

Answer (score 1):

I was with the same problem and i discovered it was because in my Gemfile, bullet was in group :development but not in group :test .